Block Theme : Query Loop with attachments
I am new to wordpress development. These day I am trying to create my own block theme in wordpress. In my theme, I have added two file upload fields to default wordpress posts using ACF pluign. It is ok and now I can upload pdf files along with new post submissions.
Problem is, I cant get those files along with my posts. Here I use the Query Loop in the site editor to get the posts into my page template. Using this block I can get only default post data like title, date, description. Can anybody tell me how I get attachments also alone with post query loop?
Home somebody may help me out.
Thank you.

Are you trying to display attachment links in the loop?
